# Cannot add boot repair to live CD

Tags: live-cd, boot-repair

I have tried to add Boot Repair through the live CD. I get an error from `add-apt-repository` when I try to add the new repository or from APT when I try to add it manually. What should I do?

Comment: Can you add more information to your question?  Namely, what error message/output etc do you get when you boot normally?  If you can't add boot repair, we have to fix the error manually...

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. Rather than trying to add the repository via the live CD, I just made a bootable flash drive with boot-repair.